# How to properly define an interface in Solidity 0.6 and above?

Tags: solidity, interfaces, solidity-0.6.x

One of the [breaking changes](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html) of solidity 0.5 was making explicit function visibility mandatory, hence all interface functions must be defined as `external` today.

In solidity 0.6, there seems to be two new function modifiers introduced: `virtual` and `override`.

How do they overlap with the previous rules for interface functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

There are two new rules to be aware of:

1. All interface functions are implicitly `virtual`. If you want to be explicit about it, the compiler throws a warning.
2. All functions inheriting from the interface must set the `override` modifier on every function that overrides an interface function, lest the compiler throws an error.

### Example

Try to see what happens if you add `virtual` or remove `override` from this:

```
interface MyInterface {

    function getBlockNumber() external view returns (uint256);
}

contract MyContract is MyInterface {

    function getBlockNumber() public view override returns (uint256) {
        return block.number;
    }
}
```

### Further Documentation

Note that the `virtual` and `override` modifiers don't apply only to interfaces. I recommend reading more about them [in this other thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78572/what-are-the-virtual-and-override-keywords-in-solidity) and the [solidity 0.6 breaking changes docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/060-breaking-changes.html).

Comment: How can you remove `virtual` in that example?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Markus, I meant to say "add virtual".