# Can abstract contracts be initialized?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, abstract

Solidity introduced [abstract contracts](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.9/contracts.html#abstract-contracts)in v0.6.

Do they behave just like in all other languages? They can't be initialized, can they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contracts marked as abstract in Solidity v0.6 and above **cannot** be initialised. Take the following files:

### Foo.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.9;

contract Foo {
  function doStuff() external virtual pure returns(string memory) {
    return "do stuff";
  }

  function doMoreStuff() external virtual pure returns(string memory) {
    return "do more stuff";
  }
}
```

### Bar.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.9;

import "./Foo.sol";

abstract contract Bar is Foo {
  function doStuff() external override pure returns(string memory) {
    return "do stuff from Bar.sol";
  }
}
```

Compile these two files in [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) and see what happens. Clicking the "Bytecode" button gives this warning in the bottom part:

[image: Remix Screen Capture]

That means that Solidity produced no bytecode for `Bar.sol`.

You may also want to read about [the "virtual" and the "override" keywords](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78572/what-are-the-virtual-and-override-keywords-in-solidity#).

Comment: Further reading: [Abstract contracts cause "call-exception" error in ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/870).