# Can't override ERC20 Methods

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin-contracts, interfaces

I try to override ERC20 methods ... The doc says it should be possible but I get the error:

```
CompileError: @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:96:5: TypeError: Trying to override non-virtual function. Did you forget to add "virtual"?
function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

The method:

```
function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
    return _totalSupply;
}
```

OpenZeppelin version: 3.3.0

Any idea of what could it be? (I'm very new to Solidity but I think that should work?)

**EDIT** Taked a bad excample... but I get this error for every function thats in ERC20 ...

Comment: I believe you have the answer here: 
 https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78572/what-are-the-virtual-and-override-keywords-in-solidity

Comment: @SergiJuanati and Ismael was an bad excample... I edit my post... I get it with every function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. It is possible to override only those functions that are declared as virtual.

For v3.3 if you inherit from ERC20 then you can override:

- transfer
- allowance
- approve
- transferFrom
- increaseAllowance
- decreaseAllowance
- _transfer
- _mint
- _burn
- _approve
- _beforeTokenTransfer

To override any other function modify a copy of ERC20.sol and inherit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Functions marked with the `override` keyword, override `virtual` functions. Functions in interfaces are by default virtual whereas virtual methods outside an interface must be explicitly marked with the `virtual` keyword.

Therefore, make sure to import IERC20.sol (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v3.3/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol) in your ERC20 contract. Next you should be able to override every method of the interface.

Comment: I dont want to take IERC20 because I also want to use mint/burn ... but I can't if I make the contract an IERC20 (that you meant by importing right? and importing ofcause)
So I need to import IERC20 and write my own mint/burn or is there another way? - btw. mint/burn I can override

Sorry for y noobish questions xD

Comment: Why can't you use the mint/burn functions of the OpenZeppelin contract ? I don't understand.

Comment: By the way, if you use the OZ ERC20 contract without IERC20.sol it will not compile.

Comment: I mint/burn is in ERC20... to override other functions I need ERC20 ... so is there a way to benefit from both? Like want  to override totalsupply() but also using mint/burn e.g.?

Comment: > By the way, if you use the OZ ERC20 contract without IERC20.sol it will not compile

It will ERC20.sol imports IERC20.sol (openzeppelin/contracts@3.3.0)