# Function with both override and virtual keywords

Tags: function, function-override, virtual

What I understood from [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78572/what-are-the-virtual-and-override-keywords-in-solidity) is that if a function has `virtual` keyword, it can be overridden. And if a function has the keyword `override` means it is overriding another function. So, does the function below means it is overriding the function `_burn` and at the same time allowing itself to be overridden?

```
function burn(uint256 tokenId) public override virtual {
    _burn(tokenId);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost. It means there's another function named `burn` that is being overridden. 
Whatever is inside this function is the new implementation, which in this case is the `_burn` function.

Everything else you mentioned is correct - `virtual` allows a function to be overridden, while `override` overrides an existing function with the same name.